# sed extract only pattern

Tags: sed

I'm having some trouble with sed. What is the right way to extract just the pattern?
For example the following returns `world`, I expect it to return just `w`

`echo "hello world" | sed -n 's|hello \(w\)|\1|p'`

Comment: Your pattern does on match the `hello w` in `hello world`. And only that match is then replaced just `w`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to match & replace (delete) the text after `w`:

```
echo "hello world" | sed -n 's|hello \(w\).*|\1|p'
```

Comment: ... same before hello? The 'w' has no preceding '\' ?

Answer (score 3):

better you can use this way.

**echo "hello world" | sed -r 's/.+(w).*/\1/'**

this will extract only the w character.
-r option is extended regular expression. so we don't use escape "\"  special characters.
. match any single character. * asterisk will match zero or more occurrences.
+ plus will match one or more occurrences.
() this is grouping method using this you can get back references.
s is used to substitute method.

Comment: `-r` is recognized by gnu sed, but there are many `sed` that do not accept that option.

Answer (score 1):

sed command if match any of the string if match only second word in first character

sed 's/([a-z].*) ([a-z]).*/\2/' inputfile